# Ruby on Rails - Sometimes the column exists, sometimes it doesn't. Is it related to this Postgres error when I dump the Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

How to correct the following errors when a load my production database into the developement?

´´´
ERROR:  relation "ar_internal_metadata" already exists
ERROR:  relation "envelopes" already exists
ERROR:  relation "envelopes_id_seq" already exists
ERROR:  relation "registers" already exists
ERROR:  relation "registers_id_seq" already exists
ERROR:  relation "schema_migrations" already exists
ERROR:  relation "signers" already exists
ERROR:  relation "signers_id_seq" already exists
ERROR:  relation "tenants" already exists
ERROR:  relation "tenants_id_seq" already exists
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ar_internal_metadata_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (key)=(environment) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY ar_internal_metadata, line 1
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "schema_migrations_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (version)=(20170523182814) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY schema_migrations, line 1
ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "ar_internal_metadata" are not allowed
ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "envelopes" are not allowed
ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "registers" are not allowed
ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "schema_migrations" are not allowed
ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "signers" are not allowed
ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "tenants" are not allowed
ERROR:  relation "index_envelopes_on_creator_id" already exists
ERROR:  relation "index_registers_on_creator_id" already exists
ERROR:  relation "index_registers_on_envelope_id" already exists
ERROR:  relation "index_signers_on_creator_id" already exists
ERROR:  relation "index_signers_on_envelope_id" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "fk_rails_60f86fe8da" for relation "registers" already exists

Answer (score 1):

Could you give more details please?

My guess is that you did:

```
$ rails db:drop
```

Then

```
@ rails db:create    
$ rails db:migrate
```

Then you got that error

Could you confirm by editing your original message. Thx

Comment: I had the same issue. I could replicate similar error with "ar_internal_metadata" with those steps.

Just to elaborate: I needed to do those steps to figure out how to create structure file when adding multiple database. After this file was created ("second_db_structure.sql"), I just ran `db:reset`.